# The throughput of ip_reasseble is low

Tags: dpdk

The throughput of ip_reasseble is low, ip_reassembly example was used to test it. Another PC2 run `iperf -c` to send ip fragments packets, the maximum throughput is about 900Mbps.

Testing setups:

```
PC1(dpdk) --- PC1(iperf -c)
PC1: 10Gb/s NIC
PC2: 1Gb/s NIC, MTU: 1500

#./build/ip_reassembly -l 2 -- -p 0x1 &
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:1f.6 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:15b7 net_e1000_em
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.1 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
IP_RSMBL: Creating LPM table on socket 0
IP_RSMBL: Creating LPM6 table on socket 0
USER1: rte_ip_frag_table_create: allocated of 25165952 bytes at socket 0
Initializing port 0 ... Port 0 modified RSS hash function based on hardware support,requested:0xa38c configured:0x8104
 Address:00:1B:21:C1:E9:C6
txq=2,0,0 

IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.10.0.0/16 (port 0)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.20.0.0/16 (port 1)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.30.0.0/16 (port 2)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.40.0.0/16 (port 3)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.50.0.0/16 (port 4)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.60.0.0/16 (port 5)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.70.0.0/16 (port 6)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 100.80.0.0/16 (port 7)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 0)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0201:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 1)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0301:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 2)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0401:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 3)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0501:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 4)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0601:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 5)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0701:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 6)
IP_RSMBL: Socket 0: adding route 0801:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101:0101/48 (port 7)

Checking link status
done
Port0 Link Up. Speed 10000 Mbps - full-duplex
IP_RSMBL: entering main loop on lcore 2
IP_RSMBL:  -- lcoreid=2 portid=0
```

run iperf -c on PC2

```
# iperf -c 192.168.10.157 -i 1 -u -t 30 -p 2152 -b 900M -l 1600
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.10.157, UDP port 2152
Sending 1600 byte datagrams, IPG target: 13.56 us (kalman adjust)
UDP buffer size:  958 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.10.100 port 37771 connected with 192.168.10.157 port 2152
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 10.0-11.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 11.0-12.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 12.0-13.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 13.0-14.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 14.0-15.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 15.0-16.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 16.0-17.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 17.0-18.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 18.0-19.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 19.0-20.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 20.0-21.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 21.0-22.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 22.0-23.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 23.0-24.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 24.0-25.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 25.0-26.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 26.0-27.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 27.0-28.0 sec   112 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 28.0-29.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] 29.0-30.0 sec   113 MBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 10 tries.
[  3]  0.0-30.0 sec  3.30 GBytes   944 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 2211842 datagrams
```

the result of ip fragments reassembled:

```
# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  335 pts/9    00:02:35 ip_reassembly
  535 pts/9    00:00:00 ps
25304 pts/9    00:00:00 su
25306 pts/9    00:00:00 zsh
# kill -SIGUSR1 335
 -- lcoreid=2 portid=0 frag tbl stat:
max entries:    4096;
entries in use: 4088;
finds/inserts:  4344078;                                                                                                                       
entries added:  883521;
entries deleted by timeout:     837;
entries reused by timeout:      0;
total add failures:     2581961;
add no-space failures:  2581961;
add hash-collisions failures:   0;
TX bursts:      0
TX packets _queued:     0
TX packets dropped:     0
TX packets send:    0
RX gtpu packets:        872727
```

I add some stats of udp port 2152 in example of ip_reassembly to show the successful reassembled
packets. According to the result, **the PC2 send 2211842 datagrams while only 872727 packets were reassembled by ip_reassembly**. When I low down the sending speed of iperf to 800Mbps, no drops print.
I don't find the throughput description in DPDK guide https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-22.07/prog_guide/ip_fragment_reassembly_lib.html
has anyone met the same questions?

Comment: please update DPDK version, details of NIC, and rerun with taskset for iperf not using DPDK logical cores. Also please cross check to run on CPU logical core that are isolated for both application.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I changed the peer PC NIC to  another one with 10Gb/s，iperf testing result was about 8Gbps，it was NIC issue, thank you.